# Angular - update a table cell

Tags: angularjs

In my angular app I have the typical table iterator via ng-repeat.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">  
    <tbody>
       <tr ng-repeat="assay in assays">
          <td>
          <td key="id">{{assay.id}}</td>
          <td key="source">{{assay.source}}</td>
          <td key="status">{{assay.status}}</td>
        ... etc ...
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Using a button a user makes a change in a modal dialog. This is all working fine, but I want to update a single cell in the table with the result; I have the id of the row as well as the field name.

Is it possible in Angular to access a single cell, or even update the entire row, if you have the index? At present I am achieving this by refreshing all the table data from the remote server... not ideal.

I guess I am looking for something like:

```
assays[id].status = 'great!'
```

Comment: When you click on the button which opens the modal dialog, this button should pass the assay object as argument. When the modal is validated, it should update the assay passed as argument. If that isn't clear enough, show more of the code.

Comment: Really? That sounds like it will be perfect. I will give it a go and post back here with the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @JB Nizet 's comment above I was able to achieve what I wanted, I think in a more angular way than I had been headed in. The angular data binding is really a great way to handle model/view updates.

I have posted a simplified version of the code here in case it helps someone else. I am using AngularUI for the modals.

**view**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">  
    <tbody>
       <tr ng-repeat="assay in assays">
          <td>
          <td key="id">{{assay.id}}</td>
          <td key="source">{{assay.source}}</td>
          <td key="status">{{assay.status}}</td>
        ... etc ...
          <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info" ng-click="invokeAssayModal(assay)">Assay</button>    
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**controller**

```
$scope.invokeAssayModal = (assay) ->
  $scope.assay = assay
  modalInstance = $modal.open(
    templateUrl: '/templates/panel/assay_modal.html'
    controller: 'AssayModalCtrl'
    windowClass: 'configure-dialog'
    resolve:
           assay: ->
             $scope.assay
)
modalInstance.result.then ((assay) ->
    $scope.assay = assay
    return
   ), ->
    return
```

**modal view**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-mini btn-success" ng-click="select(primerPair)">Select</button>
```

**modal controller**

```
$scope.select = (primerPair) ->
  $scope.assay.source = primerPair.source
```